# what is the difference between agents and objects in netlogo?

Tags: object, netlogo, agents

I just started learning netlogo. I was asked to give difference between agents and objects. I have searched for the solution on several websites but all I've learned is that Agents are beings that can follow instructions. In NetLogo, there are four types of agents: turtles, patches, links, and the observer. However I don't have any idea yet what objects are in Netlogo.

Thanks for any help..

Comment: Objects is not really a NetLogo term. Perhaps your instructor is asking how NetLogo agents match against whatever you have been given in lectures or textbook as the definition of an object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique answer to this question.  But [here](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~far/Lectures/SENG697/PDF/tutorials/2002/Comparison_of_Objects_and_Agents.pdf) is one view.